# planet with distortion in probability

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the name of the author and a book (or series of books). It is a SF/fantasy mix, probably written in the 90's or later.

The story plays on a planet where there is something seriously wrong with the laws of probability.
It is a planet with lifeforms present before colonisation by humans. These lifeforms can "steer" their path of evolution by manipulating the probabilities. The humans find out that only very strong emotions in 1 person, or emotions (faith) carried by many persons seem to stablize the probability. The disturbed probability makes things like guns, powder, explosives very unreliable and dangerous. If i remember well there are also "demons" in the story.
The first book starts with some kind of nobleman slaughtering his wife and childeren in a cruel way, which gives him for a longer period certain semi-magical powers.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214431/sci-fi-fantasy-book-people-stranded-on-a-planet-where-tech-doesnt-work-magic (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

The [Coldfire Trilogy](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/ColdfireTrilogy?from=Main.ColdfireTrilogy) by C.S. Friedman. [Black Sun Rising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Sun_Rising) (1991) is the first book.

Gerald Tarrant is the nobleman who sacrifices his family.

Comment: **WARNING** That first link is to TVTropes.. You can lose hours there if you don't watch yourself :)

Comment: I clicked it 12.99 hours ago and I've only just got back...